# How to make prism-editor on vue component show line numbers correctly when there is a break line?

Tags: vue-component

I am using prism-editor with vuetify as:

```
<prism-editor
  v-model="myValue"
  class="my-class"
  line-numbers
>
```

The issue is that if I add a text without any spaces or break lines for 3 lines length, then I add another line with a break line at the end, and then another line, it will show me that I have 3 lines as a line-numbers, but the numbers are not showing correctly beside each corresponding line! (see attached photos below, where number '2' needs to be beside the w's line, and number '3' needs to be beside the r's line).

[image]

Is it something I can fix so that each number is displayed beside it's corresponding line? if yes, what needs to be changed?

Thanks.